# How to create a rectangle polygon with set lengths in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, length

I have a search area i want to outline. and i need it to be 1km by 2km. is it possible to achieve this in QGIS.

I can create a rectangle polygon but only guess the lengths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Improved Polygon Capturing" plugin will let you specify line lengths as you draw. The CAD Tools ortho tool will let you draw 90 degree angles. However, unfortunately it doesn't seem like the two will work together!

Answer (score 2):

The way I will do it involve to steps
1)make a point layer where you can control the limits of the rectangle
2)Make a new polygon layer, set the proper snapping options, in order that you can trace the polygon by snapping the points,

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the GRASS plugin. GRASS has a module called v.mkgrid. You can either set the number of rows and columns, or the width/length of each grid cell. The grid is created within the current GRASS region.

The plugin interface within QGIS allows to set only the number of rows and columns. But if you run the module in the GRASS "shell" you can alternatively use the parameter "box=2000,1000" to get your required size.