# CAD Like functions in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

Is it possible for a script to be built that will use a reference point and have it draw several polygons based on distance and bearing, then assess the terrain under the polygon for highest obstacles or terrain?  I know there is a gent on github that has the formulas built to identify the locations, I need to extend that capability by assessing underlying terrain.

Comment: Perhaps you could reference the github page...

Comment: Yes is the short answer - if you know Python and the QGIS API.  I'm not sure why this is particularly CAD-like though, it sounds like run-of-the-mill GIS data analysis to me.

Answer (score 3):

The "Improved Polygon Capturing" plugin will let you specify line lengths as you draw. The CAD Tools ortho tool will let you draw 90 degree angles. However, unfortunately it doesn't seem like the two will work together!

one of the answers i got to a similar question:

[How to create a rectangle polygon with set lengths in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30966/create-a-rectangle-polygon-with-set-lengths-qgis)

there are some degrees of functions but alas there is not all the functionality.

I would love for both programmes to be compatible.

Comment: Fetzer, here is the link: https://github.com/pkohut/GeoFormulas

Comment: That last comment was to Fezter, not Fetzer, sorry.  Also - for MappaGnosis, I am far from capable of working with Pyhton or the QGIS API.  I am hoping to use QGIS to conduct assessments of obstacles within areas that would be described using the formulas in the FAA formulas on above website.